# Animated/ responsive/ live icons on rollover. Example given

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, jquery-svg

I'm trying to find out how to recreate the effects of the icons here:

https://designmodo.com/flat/

especially the retina display icon with the moveable lens.

However, after 2 days of trying to look for a solution/ tutorial I still couldn't find anything like that.

I've looked into JS solutions as well as HTML5 Canvas. Perhaps I've been looking in the wrong place or with the wrong search terms.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Cheers
Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're using SVG images (with a PNG fallback for older browsers) and animating certain paths in the SVG using JS and CSS.

Explanation of the technique here http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: Is this a 30 minutes job or a 6 hours job?  Do you know of any library that does it easily? From what I gather from svg.js or raphael.js, and with my limited understanding, it feels like it would take about a couple hours to animate each of those. Reason for asking is that I have no interest in reinventing the wheel if it's already there, somewhat like programming your own blog framework vs using Wordpress.

Comment: Completely dependant on the complexity of the image and your skill/experience levels. I've used Raphael.js in the past; certainly faster than trying to push things around with raw javascript, but it still helps to have good SVG exports to start with. For software that might help, have a look at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/tool-to-create-animated-svgs